# Promotion on Youtube

Tags: discussion

There are many training videos on Youtube and quite often many questions are asked in the comments.

Is it OK to link back directly to pets.stackexchange? Is it considered spamming on Youtube?

Comment: You may need to ask Google that question... :) Linking to the site, here, is okay though, there's even a badge for it.

Answer (score 3):

From [YouTube's community guidelines](https://www.youtube.com/t/community_guidelines):

```
Everyone hates spam. Don’t create misleading descriptions, tags, titles or thumbnails 
in order to increase views. It's not okay to post large amounts of untargeted, unwanted
or repetitive content, including comments and private messages.
```

So it could be considered spam if it's posted in a lot of video comments. I can't say how they filter their links exactly, but I'm sure their filter looks at links and how often the link has been posted across the site.

With that in mind, I'd do it carefully.

My suggestion would be to try and give them a link to a Q&A of their question that already exists rather than just giving a link to the homepage. You could even ask their question, and give them a link to it when it's been answered.

That way, it not only follows YouTube's guidelines more closely, but it's more impressive I think when we show answers rather than a place to ask questions. I think people will be more likely to remember the site as the place to find answers if they see them first.